# Euler number in terms of Betti numbers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, betti-numbers

This is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325595/betti-numbers-and-the-neron-severi-group) question. 
In the Paper [On the Mordell-Weil lattices](http://www.rkmath.rikkyo.ac.jp/math/shioda/papers/mwl.pdf) (p. 28, Lemma 10.1) it is proved that the rank $\rho$ of the Néron-Severi lattice of a rational elliptic surface is 10. In the proof the author states that $c_2 = b_2 + 2 - 2b_1$, where $c_2$ is the topological Euler number and the $b_i$ are the Betti numbers. As far as I know the actual definition of $c_2$ would be $c_2 = b_0 - b_1 + b_2$.  But this surely contradicts the result of the paper, as we would then have $\rho = b_2 = 11$, as $c_2$ = 12 and $b_0$ = 1. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the confusion here has to do with the difference between real and complex dimension. Your formula for the Euler characteristic is true for *real* surfaces, but the paper is about *complex* surfaces, which as real manifolds are 4-dimensional. So the Euler characteristic is $b_0-b_1+b_2-b_3+b_4$; now use $b_0=1$ and Poincaré duality.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb now! The real embarrassing fact is that I even wondered why Poincaré duality gives a wrong result in "my case". Thanks again.

Comment: Don't feel dumb! These things are always confusing when you learn them first.